# How to reference a custom 'ConnectionProvider' in EclipseLink?

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, jpa, eclipselink, h2

In Hibernate I can define the property named: `hibernate.connection.provider_class` to declare a class which should be used by Hibernate to create new Connections. This class must implement the interface `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider`. Is there anything similar in EclipseLink?

The use case behind that is, that I want to wrap jdbc-connections created by a JPA-Provider using a class which allows it to manipulate the statements sent to the JDBC-Driver.

For instance I want to remove sql-hints used in productive code to be able to replace the productive database during tests by H2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the official documentation in the [EclipseLink JavaDoc](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm#CFAEDDCC) (version 2.6.x), you can use:

> `<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.connector" value="package.MyConnector"/>`

in your `persistence.xml`. By doing so, you can refer to a class `MyConnector` which has to implement the *interface* [`org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Connector`](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/Connector.html) that defines methods which

> *allow TopLink to acquire a Connection to a JDBC database*.

I think, hereby it should be possible to "configure" connections the way you describe it.

*FYI*: 
You might extend from [`org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector`](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/DefaultConnector.html) in case you have typical (JDBC) configuration parameters at hand.

Hope it helps.